# Error initiating Ubuntu

Tags: boot

After trying to install some dependencies, the following error occurred on Ubuntu (recent version):

[image]

The full error message in red color is:

```
Failed to start default target: 
Transaction for graphical.target is destructive 
(emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction)
```

Comment: Can you grab a Live USB to boot and access the log files? Sometimes this error can happen when a partition containing your home directory needs to be fixed, but the logs will make this clear 

Comment: Please be specific; what is a *recent* version of Ubuntu?  What do you mean by "*install some dependencies*" as that might be related so being specific helps us to help you.  (*did you cleanly shutdown last session? or force shutdown?, have power cut off? etc*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to start default target: Transaction for.graphical.target/start is destructive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439112/failed-to-start-default-target-transaction-for-graphical-target-start-is-destru)