# Failed to start default target: Transaction for.graphical.target/start is destructive

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have installed Nvidia drivers then I restarted the laptop. When I typed `exit` on `root@name:~#` terminal, the following message appears in red:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for.graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has ‘start’ job queued, but ‘stop’ is included in transaction)
```

[image: screenshot showing the error message]

Can I downgrade to default graphics drivers using the terminal?

Answer (score 13):

This is probably too late for you, but I just helped a friend with this same issue. The solution was simple. It has to do with a disk not being able to be mounted.

In your case in particular and looking at your included image, I can not see the very first lines that it printed out, which would be helpful--it tells which disk is not able to be mounted.

In my friend's case, in the `/etc/fstab` file, there was an extra entry for an external USB hard drive. For some reason, the system wasn't able to find it at boot, and it caused this same draconian message that you're getting.

The solution was simply to edit the file using `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and put a `#` at the start of the relevant line to prevent the line from being active. Reboot and computer should start up normally.

This whole thing happened when updating Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.

Comment: thanks, you saved my life

Comment: Yes this was the case for me, too. I had a iscsi -mount not mounted. For me the solution was to run in the recovery console:
mount -a

Comment: Thanks, the `mount -a` really helped. Just a sidenote that might be relevant, I was worried about commenting the /boot/efi partition, but it was not an issue.

Comment: You saved my life. I almost go crazy about this error and not being able to boot. Then I did this and found an entry for a partition I deleted yesterday. I can breathe again. Thanks